# Putting a polynomial into tensor form

Tags: polynomials, tensors

I have some polynomial $f(x_{\mu}, b_{\mu})$. I suspect that I may be able to express it as the contraction of a rank-2 tensor with two vectors, e.g.

$$ f(x_{\mu}, b_{\mu}) = A^{\mu \nu}(x_{\mu}) b_{\mu} b_{\nu}$$

Is there a way to check if this is true, and determine $A^{\mu \nu}$?

Sorry for the lack of an attempt at a solution - I am utterly stumped.

Thanks

**Edits in response to comments**

The range of $\mu$ is $0-3$. The general form of the polynomial is

$$ f(x_{\mu}, b_{\mu}) = C(x_{\mu}) b^{\mu}b_{\mu} + D(x_{\mu}, b_{\mu})$$

Comment: Is this a mathematics question or one about the software product *Mathematica*?

Comment: It is a *Mathematica* question - I want to verify the above using Mathematica.

Comment: Can you give an example of a polynomial? Maybe one you know can be written as such a contraction?

Comment: There are two problems with that: i) The polynomial in question is *very* long - think ~100 terms. ii) I am not certain that this polynomial *can* be written as a contraction - this is what I want to check with Mathematica.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not talking about the full problem, but a test case that we can work on. How many variables are we talking (range of $\mu$)? Any relationship between them? What are the b?

Comment: Maybe you could set all but 3 of your $b$'s to zero to obtain a small example  that could be added to your question.  Note that your $A^{\mu\nu}$ is not unique, since you can add any anti-symmetric tensor to it and get the same $f$.  If your polynomial is a quadratic form, then to find the $n, m$ component of the symmetric $A^{\mu \nu}$, evaluate $D[f, bn, bm]/2$ in MMA.

Comment: *An example is essential.*  Anyone who would work on an answer will need a short example, and if you don't give them one, they will have to invent it.  Do not let people come up with one on their own: do this yourself.  What very often happens in these cases is that the OP ends up saying, "this is a nice solution that works for *your* example, but I cannot use it for mine."  Try to avoid this.